# Why does MathJax not seem to be working properly in the output of my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax

I'm trying to write a simple program that generates dot product questions. The code I have used is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</script>
</head>



<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate Question</button>

<br>
<br>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<hr>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

var dot = (a*x)+(b*y)+(c*z);





document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Find the       solution to the dot product (" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")" + "$\.   \cdot$" + "(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ")";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Solution: (" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")" + "$\\cdot$" + "(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ") = " + dot;

MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, document.getElementById("demo")]);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, the output this gives looks like

[image: output]

Why does it render in this way? It works properly in the solution, but not in the question.

Comment: Is this just about escaping backslashes in JavaScript strings?

Comment: Write `\u2219` and you don't need MathJax to typeset &#x2219;. Apart from that, ``\`` in string literals have to be escaped, and `\.` isn't a MathJax command by default. If one solution works and the other does not, it pays to look closely at the differences, and you should be able to spot those.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the missing double backslash pointed out by Peter and MvG in comments above, the reason the first math isn't typeset is that you have only asked MathJax to typeset the `"demo"` element, and the other math is in the `"demo2"` element.  Try using

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, ["demo2","demo"]]);
```

instead.